# Axiomatic proof in S4

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I'm trying to prove the following formula in S4.

$\Box \Diamond \Box \Diamond P \rightarrow \Box \Diamond P$

I have mp, nec, K,D,T,S4 as well as the derived rule $\Diamond \Diamond \phi \rightarrow \Diamond \phi$. I also am able to make obvious moves from propositional logic. i.e. going from $\phi \rightarrow \psi$ to $(\phi \land \sigma) \rightarrow \psi$ etc.

But I can't seem to figure this deduction out. Each time I end up with an extra $\Diamond$ or $\Box$.

Comment: Welcome to math S.E. It helps us answer your question if you provide your own attempts at it in the body of the question itself. This also allows us to avoid doing students homework for them (completely).

Comment: Do you know/accept a model theoretic proof?

Comment: No, I'm trying to prove it axiomatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first note that in system K, we have derived rules: if $\varphi \rightarrow \psi$ is a theorem, then (a) $\square \varphi\rightarrow \square \psi$ is a theorem, and (b) $\lozenge \varphi\rightarrow \lozenge \psi$ is a theorem. For (a), assume $\varphi\rightarrow \psi$ is a theorem. By necessitation, $\square(\varphi\rightarrow \psi)$. By $(K)$ and modus ponens, $\square \varphi\rightarrow \square \psi$. For (b), assume $\varphi\rightarrow \psi$ is a theorem. Then $\lnot \psi\rightarrow \lnot \varphi$ is a theorem. By (a), $\square \lnot \psi\rightarrow \square \lnot \varphi$. Taking the contrapositive again, $\lozenge \varphi\rightarrow \lozenge \psi$.

Ok, now for the proof. By $(T)$, $\square \lozenge P\rightarrow \lozenge P$. By (b), $\lozenge \square \lozenge P\rightarrow \lozenge\lozenge P$. By the derived rule $\lozenge\lozenge \varphi\rightarrow \lozenge \varphi$ you mentioned in your question, $\lozenge \square \lozenge P\rightarrow\lozenge P$. By (a), $\square\lozenge \square \lozenge P\rightarrow\square\lozenge P$, as desired.

Note that the proof used modus ponens, necessitation, $(K)$, $(T)$, and $(4)$ in the form of the derived rule from your question. The proof did not use $(D)$, and indeed $(D)$ is usually not taken as an axiom in S4 modal logic.

Comment: Necessitation only works on theorems, not assumptions.

Comment: @GrahamKemp right right. I shouldn't have stated the derived rule as an implication! I'll edit.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Better now, I hope. Thanks for pointing this out!